# SVG анимация прямоугольного пути и его затемение

Tags: css, css3, html5, svg, css-animation

Можно ли анимировать весь этот путь целиком, используя SVG-анимацию, сверху вниз, один участок за другим  включая точки?

Код ниже не имеет `paths`.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="495.303" height="422.699" viewBox="0 0 495.303 422.699">
  <g id="Group_110" data-name="Group 110" transform="translate(-670 -3225.301)">
    <rect id="Rectangle_172" data-name="Rectangle 172" width="244" height="1" transform="translate(961 3394) rotate(90)" fill="#57af2d"/>
    <rect id="Rectangle_173" data-name="Rectangle 173" width="269" height="1" transform="translate(691 3636.5)" fill="#57af2d"/>
    <ellipse id="Ellipse_289" data-name="Ellipse 289" cx="4" cy="4" rx="4" ry="4" transform="translate(964.303 3641.301) rotate(180)" fill="#57af2d"/>
    <circle id="Ellipse_298" data-name="Ellipse 298" cx="11.5" cy="11.5" r="11.5" transform="translate(670 3625)" fill="#57af2d"/>
    <rect id="Rectangle_174" data-name="Rectangle 174" width="202" height="1" transform="translate(960 3393)" fill="#57af2d"/>
    <ellipse id="Ellipse_291" data-name="Ellipse 291" cx="4" cy="4" rx="4" ry="4" transform="translate(964.303 3398.301) rotate(180)" fill="#57af2d"/>
    <ellipse id="Ellipse_292" data-name="Ellipse 292" cx="4" cy="4" rx="4" ry="4" transform="translate(1165.303 3398.301) rotate(180)" fill="#57af2d"/>
    <rect id="Rectangle_176" data-name="Rectangle 176" width="165" height="1" transform="translate(1162 3229) rotate(90)" fill="#57af2d"/>
    <ellipse id="Ellipse_294" data-name="Ellipse 294" cx="4" cy="4" rx="4" ry="4" transform="translate(1165.303 3233.301) rotate(180)" fill="#57af2d"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/56274585/7394871

Comment: Я выбрал этот топик для перевода, так как здесь применена интересная техника для практического применения анимации линий, имеющих разную ширину линий, имеющих дополнительные элементы на линии, - круги, эллипсы. Всё это может быть использовано для оживления веб страничек при скроллинге. А также при реализации анимации написания слова с разной шириной строк букв (Handwriting )  Пример - https://codepen.io/dinog28/pen/VpJyKV

Comment: Здравствуйте просветите пожалуйста в svg анимации использовать js надо ? или svg все делает сам ?

Comment: @Leks Здравствуйте. Любая комбинация возможна css+Js+svg/ Очень мощная связка, очень хорошо сочетаются. CSS и JS могут быть, как внутри SVG, так и снаружи. И svg может всё сделать сам без CSS и JS

Comment: скажите пожалуйста а долго учить svg (без js) ?

Comment: @Leks извините, это уже офтопик. Давайте будем завершать  Почитайте https://svg-art.ru/, http://css.yoksel.ru/ и другие сайты, посвященные svg и для себя решите сможете или нет освоить svg в короткий срок.

Comment: ок спасибо что уделили внимание

Answer (score 2):

Безусловно, лучшее и простое решение, - переписать код SVG, чтобы  использовался `<path>` для ломанной линии. 
Если вы не можете этого сделать, тогда можно использовать путь в маске, для точного повторения трассировки ломанной кривой.
Путь (в маске) следует за вашей ломанной линией, и когда вы анимируете изменение его длины, он показывает реальный путь, который до этого был скрыт маской.

```css
#revealer path {
  animation: reveal 3s linear forwards;
  stroke-dashoffset: 906px;
}

@keyframes reveal {
  from { stroke-dashoffset: 906px; }
  to   { stroke-dashoffset: 0px; }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="495.303" height="422.699" viewBox="0 0 495.303 422.699">
  <defs>
    <mask id="revealer">
      <path d="M 492,0 L 492,168 L 290,168 L 290,412 L 0,412" fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="26" stroke-dasharray="906 906"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>

  <g mask="url(#revealer)">
  <g id="Group_110" data-name="Group 110" transform="translate(-670 -3225.301)">
    <rect id="Rectangle_172" data-name="Rectangle 172" width="244" height="1" transform="translate(961 3394) rotate(90)" fill="#57af2d"/>
    <rect id="Rectangle_173" data-name="Rectangle 173" width="269" height="1" transform="translate(691 3636.5)" fill="#57af2d"/>
    <ellipse id="Ellipse_289" data-name="Ellipse 289" cx="4" cy="4" rx="4" ry="4" transform="translate(964.303 3641.301) rotate(180)" fill="#57af2d"/>
    <circle id="Ellipse_298" data-name="Ellipse 298" cx="11.5" cy="11.5" r="11.5" transform="translate(670 3625)" fill="#57af2d"/>
    <rect id="Rectangle_174" data-name="Rectangle 174" width="202" height="1" transform="translate(960 3393)" fill="#57af2d"/>
    <ellipse id="Ellipse_291" data-name="Ellipse 291" cx="4" cy="4" rx="4" ry="4" transform="translate(964.303 3398.301) rotate(180)" fill="#57af2d"/>
    <ellipse id="Ellipse_292" data-name="Ellipse 292" cx="4" cy="4" rx="4" ry="4" transform="translate(1165.303 3398.301) rotate(180)" fill="#57af2d"/>
    <rect id="Rectangle_176" data-name="Rectangle 176" width="165" height="1" transform="translate(1162 3229) rotate(90)" fill="#57af2d"/>
    <ellipse id="Ellipse_294" data-name="Ellipse 294" cx="4" cy="4" rx="4" ry="4" transform="translate(1165.303 3233.301) rotate(180)" fill="#57af2d"/>
  </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Сразу по эффекту понял как это сделано не глядя в код :)